# How I can send an email with my work email address using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtp, smtplib

I want to send a computer-generated email by my work email address using a python script. All of the tutorials I found were about Gmail account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send pdf file and html using gmail smtplib

1- Allow less secure apps in gmail apps

2- use smtplib to send an email

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

filename = "filename.pdf"
receivers = ["receiver@gmail.com"]
subject= "Email subject"

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = "Me"
message['To'] = '_'.join(receivers)
message["Subject"] = subject

with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)

part.add_header(
"Content-Disposition",
f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
)

html = """\
<p>
HTML data
</P>
"""
message.attach(part)
message.attach(MIMEText(html, "html"))
message = message.as_string()
# start TLS for security user_to
server.starttls()

# Authentication 
server.login("me@gmail.com", "password")
sender = "email"

try:
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
except Exception as e:
    raise e
```